# Show $\forall x \exists y F(x,y)$ does not imply $\exists y \forall x F(x,y)$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Show:

$\exists y \forall x R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$

$\forall x \exists y F(x,y)$ does not imply $\exists y \forall x F(x,y)$

How do proofs of this nature usually work? When I try to prove the first one by saying:

$\mathcal{M} \models R(n,m)$ for all $n$ and some $m$ in the domain, so $\mathcal{M} \models \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$, I don't see why the same can't be applied for the second problem with $F(x,y)$. Can someone help me to intuitively understand these operations?

Comment: In general, the way of proving that an implication does not hold is to provide a counterexample (that is, a structure $\mathcal{M}$) that satisfies the left-hand side but not the right-hand side of the implication. [Here is a counterexample and some intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3145676/344246) for the problem in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the domain of the variables $x$ and $y$ be interpreted as the set of all people and let the statement $F(x,y)$ be interpreted as “$y$ is the mother of $x$.”

Then, $\forall x\exists yF(x,y)$ means that everybody has a mother (duh), while $\exists y\forall x F(x,y)$ means that there is a person who is everybody's mother (utter nonsense).

Answer (score 4):

We can draw a table of all truth values of $F$ whose rows correspond to values of $x$ and whose columns correspond to values of $y$. (if it helps, consider a domain such that the universe only has two elements, so this is a $2\times 2$ table)

$\forall x \exists y F(x,y)$ means that every row contains at least one $\top$.

$\exists y \forall x F(x,y)$ means that there exists a column consisting entirely of $\top$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sentences $\forall x\exists y\ x=y$ and $\exists y\forall x\ x=y$ in a domain with two elements.

Answer (score 2):

"does not imply" is almost always proved by a counter-example. Let be $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ domain of F(x,y) defined by F(x,y) if only if x=2y.Then, ∀x∃y such that x=2y (obviously) i.e., F(x,y), but there is no y in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that x=2y for all x in $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Shaun's answer, however, it uses different software.

One can [generate a tree proof](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%83y%E2%88%80xRxy%E2%86%92%E2%88%80x%E2%88%83yRxy) for the first one that closes as follows:

[image]

However, for the second one the [tree proof](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%80x%E2%88%83yFxy%E2%86%92%E2%88%83y%E2%88%80xFxy) does not close allowing a countermodel to be constructed showing it is invalid:

[image]

The countermodel specifies a domain with two members, $0$ and $1$. The predicate $F$ is true for the pairs $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. It is false for all other pairs, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. That means for all $x$ there exists $y$ such that $Fxy$ is true. So the antecedent is true. However, it is not true that there exists a $y$ such that all $x$ $Fxy$ true. So the consequent is false.

All one has to do to prove invalidity is to find a countermodel showing the antecedent is true while the consequent is false.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/trees/

Answer (score 1):

An informal way to prove these is with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux), explained in detail in M. D’Agostino *et al.*'s *"Handbook of Tableau Methods."*

You start with the negation of statement you're interested in and apply a systematic search for a contradiction. For example:

[image],

which closed (i.e. it ends in a contradiction). This is equivalent to a proof in many semantics.

Comment: [Here's the code for the diagram above.](https://www.writelatex.com/679519jwwxkp#/1441827/)